# EmberJS linkTo nested resource is re-rendering the parent view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a simple interface with a list of links on the left, retrieved from an AJAX call, that, when clicked, open in an *{{outlet}}* to the right with some data, retrieved as well from another AJAX call from that link. So these are my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('subreddit', { path: 'subreddit/:subreddit_name' }, function() {
    this.resource('comments', { path: 'comments/:id' })
    });
});
```

So I have a dynamic list of links, based on :subreddit_name with the following structure:

```
subreddit/:subreddit_name/comments/:id
```

To create the links I have the following codeblock:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="subreddit">  
    <div>    
        {{#each item in model}}
            {{#linkTo 'comments' item.subreddit item.id classNames="list-group-item"}}
                <img class="media-object" {{bindAttr src="item.thumbnail"}} class="img-rounded">
                {{item.author}}                    
            {{/linkTo}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>

    <div>{{outlet}}</div>
</script>
```

The link is properly corrected, but, after I've inserted the :subreddit_name dynamic route to the Router, when I click the link it re-renders the whole template, instead of re-rendering only the template for the comments:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="comments">
{{#each item in model}}
  <div class="panel panel-info mypanel">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{item.author}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <p>{{{item.body}}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

I'm still pretty green on EmberJS, that's why I would like to ask for some suggestion/commment on out to correct this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to pass **only** the model as a parameter in the `link-to` helper,  instead of the parent model and the id. Like this: `{{#linkTo 'comments' item}}` in the `subreddit` template

Comment: It works.. almost! The thing is, when I click the link it retrieves the proper comments but the URL is: "index.html#/subreddit/undefined/comments/1t0gwe" where 'undefined' should be the name of the subreddit

Comment: Problem is there's nobody telling the `SubredditRoute` the model it'll be used. Its undefined ATM, that's why when it tries serializes it (to change the url) it shows `undefined`. What I think you should do is have a route that handles and displays all the subreddits, then one that handles one subreddit (that display links to the comments) and then the one for the comment. **EDIT** I'm having my doubts... try to use your first `link-to` approach, but take a look at this method: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize

Comment: edpaez will you put your comments in the answer, he does need to implement the serialize hook for the route.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I will inform myself on the serialize hook! Please put you comment as an answer since it was really relevant! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry didn't work :S Or probably I'm not implementing it right. The problem is still  on the linkTo tag, keeps rendering undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsbin working example:

http://jsbin.com/OlOJEwAX/4/edit?html,js,output

I've managed to get the links working but the undefined is also there rendered :S